# Import a Single Field Text File into MySQL

Tags: mysql, import

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
value1
value2
value3
```

There are 32 million lines. Each line is terminated by a \n. The fields are not enclosed or delimited with any characters. I'm trying to import it into MySQL using this code, but it is not working:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.txt'
INTO TABLE `table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(`column1`)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you say it's not working, what specifically happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was being too explicit. This did it:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.txt'
INTO TABLE `table`
ENCLOSED BY ''
(`column1`)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try using double quotes instead of single quotes? it might be interpreting '\n' as a literal - this happens in some other languages and might be the case here